# How to put a certain large number into a register in LC3 assembly?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to have a register (say R1) storing a particular number that's too big for an immediate (say 440). Obviously I cannot just set R1 to 0 and use ADD, is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: If you ever looked at any sample code, you would have seen it uses the `.FILL` directive to store the value in memory and just load it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your registers are 16 bits, so 440 clearly fits in there, but the immediate fields are 5 bits, so it clearly won't fit in there.  Memory is also 16 bits wide, so you can store it in memory:

```
toobig: .word 440
```

Then get it with a direct memory read

```
LD R1, toobig
```